# What is the fourth columns' meaning of Xcode's setting?

Tags: xcode

[image]

choose the project  -> build setting -> all

what is the fourth columns of Build Options?

What is the difference between the second and third column?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are settings that come from different places. For a project, it will be 'Resolved' on the left, then your project, then defaults. For a target, it will go 'Resolved', then your target, then your project, then defaults. It's showing you what the default setting would be on the right, your project's override (if any) next to that, the target's override (if any) next to that, and the actual settings you end up with on the left.

Also note that you can click on 'Combined' at the top instead of 'Levels' if you prefer not to see your settings this way. Project/target overrides will still be in bold.

Comment: Anyone know how to view all contents of Resolved when the content is very long so it does not fit in the view? It cannot be scrolled or anything right.